# What's the difference between "granjero" and "campesino"?

Tags: definiciones

What's the difference in usage between **granjero** and **campesino**?  They both mean *farmer*, don't they?

Comment: Campesino is just someone who lives in the countryside.

Comment: Y los agricultores?

Comment: I'd say it's more or less like the difference between *farmer* and *peasant*

Comment: "Labrador" is also a farmer.

Answer (score 6):

For someone who works in a farm you would use, most commonly at least, **granjero**.

The root for *campesino* is *campo* (field, as in rural areas) and for *granjero* is *granja* (farm).

Answer (score 2):

I agree with JMVanPelt that **campesino** is a peasant and **granjero** is a farmer.

The other words from the comments refer to people who work the fields (not necessarily in a farm) and differ in the origin of the word

[Agricultor:](http://dle.rae.es/?id=19vVDdp) Del lat. agricultor, -ōris.
[Labrador:](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Mjdglg8%7CMjf4tIk) Del lat. tardío laborātor, -ōris 'el que trabaja'.
[Labriego:](http://dle.rae.es/?id=MkAfgyI) De labrar y -iego.

Answer (score 0):

This may come to most Americans as a shock, but to the Colombians, the term "campesino" literally means "peasant."  Campesinos more or less are landless peasants that are tied to the land by custom and tradition.